# Oracle SQL nested relationship into on level

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

If I have the following table:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
A        B
C        D
D        E
B        C
```

How can I write a sql to get the following:

```
ColumnC  ColumnD
A        B
A        C
A        D
A        E
B        C
B        D
B        E
C        D
C        E
D        E
```

The level of nested relationship many be multiple.
Can sql handle this? Or need PLSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive CTE might help.

```
SQL> with
  2  test (cola, colb) as
  3    -- sample data; you already have that
  4    (select 'a', 'b' from dual union all
  5     select 'c', 'd' from dual union all
  6     select 'd', 'e' from dual union all
  7     select 'b', 'c' from dual
  8    ),
  9  -- recursive CTE
 10  temp (parent, child) as
 11    (select t.cola parent, t.colb child
 12       from test t
 13     union all
 14     select a.parent, b.colb child
 15       from temp a join test b on a.child = b.cola
 16    )
 17  select *
 18  from temp
 19  order by parent, child;

PARENT     CHILD
---------- ----------
a          b
a          c
a          d
a          e
b          c
b          d
b          e
c          d
c          e
d          e

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: You're welcome; also, you should consider upvoting/acception answer(s) you find useful.

Comment: Pls help with the similar question with different istuation
https://stackoverflow.com/q/60965028/13127544?sem=2

Answer (score 2):

Use a hierarchical query with `CONNECT_BY_ROOT`:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( ColumnA ) AS ColumnA,
       ColumnB
FROM   table_name
CONNECT BY PRIOR ColumnB = ColumnA
```

For your data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ColumnA, ColumnB ) AS
SELECT 'A', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 'E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'C' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> COLUMNA | COLUMNB
> :------ | :------
> A       | B      
> A       | C      
> A       | D      
> A       | E      
> B       | C      
> B       | D      
> B       | E      
> C       | D      
> C       | E      
> D       | E
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a78110bcfbd4e986b08096ee589e3f34)*

Comment: Ah, nice! Connect_by_root!

Comment: Works for the current situation! But it does not work when adding extract columnC. Need columnC to be the same

Comment: @vllll "Need ColumnC to be the same" What does that mean? There is no ColumnC in your example. If you want to add additional requirements then that should be part of your original question because we can't answer a question or meet requirements that you did not tell us about. So, if you have a different question with different requirements then please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @vllll There are plenty of ways for "ColumnC to be the same". Some examples are [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0407b46c08535f3e27e70b72ac360243).