# Oracle SQL nested relationship into one level

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

```
ColumnA ColumnB  ColumnC ColumnD
A        B        C        E
D        C        F        E
C        H        I        E
C        W        S        E1
```

The logic should be when columnA/columnB has a record in columnC which is columnA/columnB in another record with the same columnD, it will be output as the following

```
ColumnV  ColumnW
A          C
B          C
D          F
C          F
C          I
H          I
C          S
W          S
A          F
B          F
A          I
B          I
```

How can I write a sql to get the following:

Comment: seem recrusive CTE can only use once union all cannot use twice

Comment: In reading your question, I'm having trouble understanding how your input maps to your output.  Can you please expand upon your logic?  Also, what have you already tried to solve this problem?

Comment: The logic should be when columnA/columnB has a record in columnC which is columnA/columnB in another record with the same value in columnD

Comment: When columnA/columnB has a record in columnC which is columnA/columnB in another record with the same value in columnD，it will be the columnV(value of columnA/columnB) and ColumnW(value columnC), please also consider the loop until there is not more child record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the logic you are trying to implement, but here is SQL that creates your table and duplicates your example output. It was tested on https://livesql.oracle.com

Please take this with a grain of salt because if your data may have duplicate rows or cycles or whatnot, that is not demonstrated in your example, the query might need modification.

Outline:

1. In the "with" clause, we pivot "ColumnA" and "ColumnB" into a single column, and add col_src to preserve which one the new "ColumnAB" is.
2. Then we recursively query, connecting by a matching column D and a column A/B that matches the previous column C.
3. To match the ordering provided, we sort by:

   - the recursion level
   - column C
   - whether the source was column A or B
   - the value of the column A or B

```
create table mytable as
select 'A' "ColumnA",'B' "ColumnB",'C' "ColumnC",'E' "ColumnD" from dual
union select 'D' "ColumnA",'C' "ColumnB",'F' "ColumnC",'E' "ColumnD" from dual
union select 'C' "ColumnA",'H' "ColumnB",'I' "ColumnC",'E' "ColumnD" from dual
union select 'C' "ColumnA",'W' "ColumnB",'S' "ColumnC",'E1' "ColumnD" from dual
;

with temp as (
    select "ColumnA" as "ColumnAB", "ColumnC", "ColumnD", 'A' as col_src
    from mytable
    union all select "ColumnB", "ColumnC", "ColumnD", 'B' as col_src
    from mytable
)
select connect_by_root("ColumnAB") "ColumnV", "ColumnC" as "ColumnW" from temp
connect by prior "ColumnD" = "ColumnD" and prior "ColumnC" = "ColumnAB"
order by level,"ColumnC",col_src,  "ColumnAB"
```

Comment: Can the sql also show the relationship direct or indirect?
Like A - C is direct and A - I is indirect?

Comment: @vllll Maybe try an expression like `case when level > 1 then 'indirect' else 'direct' end`.